# PWA crashes if it does not work offline as of Chrome 86?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm looking to publish my webapp on the Play Store, and I have found https://pwabuilder.com which lets you easily turn your website into an app.

I have completed their simple process and am now reading the readme, where I read this section:

[image]

It looks like Chrome 86 is the latest Chrome, so it looks like this is a very recent change?

I'm confused though, because my app is *entirely* online. That is, cached data is useless. In conclusion, the webapp is completely useless when offline.

In addition, I am already using a service worker worker in the root scope for push notifications, so I cannot simply add another one. It seems that now I am required to complicate my app and cache static assets that are entirely useless, just so that the app doesn't purposefully crash? Is this actually the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, this is only applicable to PWAs that are delivered through the Play Store using Trusted Web Activities, though it will become a requirement for PWAs in the future.

If your PWA requires an internet connection, I recommend using a simple offline fallback page. That way, if the user is offline, at least they get a branded offline page instead of the browser provided offline page. Check out https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/ for details on how to create an offline fallback page.

Comment: An offline page is a perfect  idea. Thanks!